# Trouble installing a package "E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: package-management

I installed some ROS components from source on a raspberry pi.  I was going through and installing the required dependencies, when I ran into this:

sudo apt install -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true -o Debug::Acquire::http=true libgpg-error-dev

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) libgpg-error-dev:armhf < none -> 1.26-2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libgpg-error-dev:armhf Depends on libgpg-error0:armhf < 1.35-1~bpo9+1 @ii mK > (= 1.26-2)
  Considering libgpg-error0:armhf 106 as a solution to libgpg-error-dev:armhf 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgpg-error-dev : Depends: libgpg-error0 (= 1.26-2) but 1.35-1~bpo9+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm not sure what's going on, nor how to resolve this.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

The installed version of `libgpg-error0` is the backported version, so you need to install the matching version of `libgpg-error-dev`:

```
sudo apt install -t stretch-backports libgpg-error-dev
```

Comment: Thanks man! I thought it had something to do with the backports, but I didn't know what.